# Commander.js mutli word argument

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, discord.js, node-commander

I am creating a discord bot with NodeJs and I want to utilize the commander.js package to make the commands a bit more structured.

I want to declare a param to give a username, eq`('-u, --user <USERNAME>', 'the user to handle')`.
This works great, until the username consists of more than 1 word. eq. John Doe. what happens is that after parsing the arguments I get a `('-u' == 'John')` and I have a leftover argument array with the word `'Doe'` in it.

I have tried passing the username between quotes. eq`node program -u "John Doe"` but the result is the same.

Am I missing something or is commander.js not capable of handling multi word arguments?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the args where wrongly splitted in another part of my bot. so this isn't an issue with either NodeJS or commander.js.

@Mods this question can be closed